# Get function given a list of values

Tags: python

Is there a way that I can give python a list of values like [ 1, 3, 4.5, 1] and obtain a function that relates to those values? like y = 3x+4 or something like that?

I don't want to plot it or anything, I just want to substitute values in that function and see what the result would be.

edit: is there a way that python can calculate how the data is related? like if I give it the list containing thousands of values and it returns me the function that was adjusted to those values.

Comment: There could be _infinitely_ many relationships between your input values.  If you're asking for a function that outputs possible relationships between arbitrary input values I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Related to what? If y is the values at hand, then what is x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments to [David Heffernan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622477/get-function-given-a-list-of-values/7622482#7622482),

> I want is to know what the relation between the values is, I have thousands of values stored in a list and I want to know if python can tell me how they are related..

it seems like you are trying do a [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) (probably a linear regression) and fit the values.

You can use [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) for linear regression analysis in Python. Here a [sample](https://web.archive.org/web/20130407175357/http://www.scipy.org:80/Cookbook/LinearRegression) from the NumPy cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the function is called [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map).

```
def y(x):
    return 3*x+4

map(y, [1,3,4.5,1])
```

The `map()` function applies the function to every item and returns a list of the results.

Comment: Hm yeah I understand that, but what I want is to know what the relation between the values is, I have thousands of values stored in a list and I want to know if python can tell me how they are related..

Comment: I suggest you edit the question to make it clear what you are looking for. "I just want to substitute values in that function and see what the result would be" implies you are looking for `map`. Also, how can you expect to supply just `y` and have the program produce both `x` and the function? That's not a well-specified problem

Comment: I think the question is "is there a function I can call that will do the `def y(x)` part for me?  I think the answer there is "no" tbh.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Indeed. Especially if the x are not specified!!

Comment: ok, sorry. Thanks for the answers though, guess I'll use some math software or something for that.

Comment: @bb2 before you try to use some math software you need to work out what the question you want answered is. At the moment you have not formulated a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to find out if the sequences `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[ 1, 3, 4.5, 1]` (or else the pairs `[(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4.5), (4, 1)]` are related with a (linear) function or not.

Try to plot these and see if they form somethign that looks like a (straight) line or not.

You can also look for correlation techniques. Check this site with basic statistic stuff (look down on correlation: **[Basic Statistics](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/basic-statistics/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your revised question, I'm going to go ahead and add an answer.  No, there is no such function.  I imagine you're unlikely to find a function that comes close in *any* programming language.  Your definitions aren't tight enough for anything to be reasonable yet.  If we take a simple case with only two input integers you can have all sorts of relationships:

```
[10, 1]
```

possible relationships:

```
def x(y):
  return y ** 0

def x(y):
  return y / 10

def x(y)
  return y % 10 + 1
```

... ... repeat.  Admittedly, some of those are arbitrary, but they are valid relationships between the first and second values in the array you passed in.  The possibilities for "solutions" become even more absurd as you ask for a relationship between 10, 15, or 35 numbers.

Comment: You are technically right but people usually are only trying to find a function that is **close enough** to the data they have. That's why many refer to statistics as ***"Lies, Big lies, Statistics"***

Comment: @ypercube - Yes, but "close enough" implies that you have some idea of the relationship ahead of time (ie, linear regression, adherence to a curve, logarithmic progression, etc.)  Without some base for deciding what is a valid relationship and what is not, the question is too open ended to answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "statistical regression".  There are many methods by which you might do this; here's a site that might help: [Least Squares Regression](http://ceee.rice.edu/Books/LA/leastsq/index.html) but ultimately, this is a field to which many books have been devoted.  There's polynomial regressions, trig regressions, logarithmic...you'll have to know something about your data before you decide which model you apply; if you don't have any knowledge of what the dataset will look like before you process it, I'd suggest comparing the residuals of whatever you get and choosing the one with the lowest sum.

Short answer: No, no function.